# Use useEffect() with tabs in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the next code:

```js
const Demo = () => (
  <Tabs defaultActiveKey="1" onChange={callback}>
    <TabPane tab="Tab 1" key="1">
      <Inner d={5} />
    </TabPane>
    <TabPane tab="Tab 2" key="2">
      <Inner d={3455} />
    </TabPane>
    <TabPane tab="Tab 3" key="3">
      <Inner d={54} />
    </TabPane>
  </Tabs>
);

// Inner

export const Inner = ({ d }) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(d, "ss");
  }, [d]);
  return <div>{d}</div>;
};
```

How you can notice inside `Inner` component i get a prop. My question is next: Why when i change the tabs clicking on each one i get inside useEffect the right data `console.log(d, "ss");`, but if i click twice on the same tab i don't get a value inside console? This happens even i added a dependency . How to get every time a value inside console even clicking twice on the same tab?  
 demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-antd4151-forked-swj43?file=/Inner.js:142-267

Comment: If you click twice on the same tab you won't change the prop called *d* so the effect won't be applied.

Comment: Could you explain what are you trying to do? If you want to get the `console.log` to work you must change the variable `d`, so if the variable `d`changes the function will be called, since the variable does not change, `useEffect` is called just once.

Comment: The Inner component useEffect will only trigger once, when it mounts. Since the d props never changes, the useEffect doesn't trigger again for a given Inner component.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of useEffect you may want to use onTabClick

| onTabClick | Callback executed when tab is clicked function(key: string, event: MouseEvent) |
| --- | --- |